# Очередь анимации

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить проблему?
Если быстро провести по блокам, они будут ещё долго открываться и закрываться.
http://jsfiddle.net/7dx7p5n0/1/

Answer (score 1):

Метод stop() решает: http://jsfiddle.net/7dx7p5n0/2/

Comment: Решает, но появляется новая проблема.
Быстро проведите по блокам и остановитесь на одном из них, информация иногда не появляется.